app center glitching on 22.04
After upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 on a VMWare instance via
do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive

I find that opening the Show Applications menu will glitch, leaving trails everywhere:
This does not happen on instances built with 22.04, or when the NVIDIA driver is uninstalled.  I've tried purging and reinstalling the NVIDIA driver, and disabling GNOME extensions; nothing helps.
